# How can I get H2 to work with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, testing, h2

I am writing a test which extends Spring's `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests`.

In my application code I have a method which I call inside the test annotated by the following:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

#### Problem

I run into a problem while using `H2` as the underlying data source in-memory mode. It gives me the error:

> `Caused by:`org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException`: Timeout trying to lock table`MY_TABLE`[50200-131]`

When I remove the propagation, it works, and when I use an alternative database such as Oracle or MySQL with `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW`, everything works fine.

I am using Spring `3.0.2-RELEASE` and `H2 1.2.131`.

How can I get `H2` to work with Spring?

Comment: Using Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW may open a new connection and as a result create a new transaction. This causes concurrency problems as there is currently running transaction in the junit spring test which has inserted data into the table causing a table lock.

I don't understand how other people using H2 have avoided this issue!

Comment: I switched to HSQLDB 1.8.0.10 and used Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW on my method under test and everything works fine. This tells me that H2 must need configuration.

Comment: How long does your transaction take? The default transaction timeout for H2 is relatively short (1 second), so unless you can make your transaction shorter, you may want to increase the LOCK_TIMEOUT setting (see the docs).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what the problem is, but try appending ;MVCC=TRUE to the database URL.

Comment: is MVCC stable? I hear it is not stable here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/h2-database/VqCzbKzTOh4 though this was in 2009 it still seems to be the case as it is not the default mode

Comment: Hi - it's still not the default, even thought it should be a lot more stable now.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem doing JUnit Tests with play-framework Jobs (that run into separate threads) and trick provided by Thomas works! (appending ;MVCC=TRUE to the database URL.)

I guess this MVCC option enables 'Row Level Locking' instead of locking the whole TABLE, and so the LOCK issue is gone, see "Row Level Locking" feature on:
http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases

'Row Level Locking' supported in H2: <*9 When using MVCC (multi version concurrency).>